# Parse to json string correct format

Tags: json, swift

I have a string inside a dictionary that I am trying to pass to jsonstring but it is not removing the backslashes and the server does not swallow it. Any ideas?

```
let myBod = "\"Body\": {" +
        "\"type\": \"multipart\"," +
        "\"content\": [" +
        "{" +
        "\"contentType\": \"multipart/alternative; Boundary=\\\"0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\\\"\"," +
        "\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\"" +
         " }," +
         "{" +
         "\"contentType\": \"text/plain; charset=US-ASCII\"," +
        "\"data\": \"yappy\"," +
         "\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"" +
         " }," +
        " {" +
        "\"contentType\": \"text/html; charset=US-ASCII\"," +
          "\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\"," +
         "\"data\": \"<html><body>yappy</body></html>\"," +
         "\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"}]}"
```

EDIT:

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataToPost, options: []) {
    if let contentJSONString = String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        // here `content` is the JSON dictionary containing the String
        dataPost.append(contentJSONString)
        print(contentJSONString)
    }
}
```

This return my string but don't disappear the backslashes.

```
JSON string = {"_Abstract":"Problema al instalar Historian 6.0 Enterprise  Info Link: https:\/\/soporte.adasoft.es\/browse\/NOVTRACERT-24","Executor":"","Watcher":[""],"Supervisor":"CÃ©sar Ramos","Name":"NOVTRACERT-24","Body":"{\"type\": \"multipart\",\"content\": [{\"contentType\": \"multipart\/alternative; Boundary=\\\"0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\\\"\",\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\" },{\"contentType\": \"text\/plain; charset=US-ASCII\",\"data\": \"Problema al instalar Historian 6.0 Enterprise\r\n\r\nInfo Link: https:\/\/soporte.adasoft.es\/browse\/NOVTRACERT-24\",\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\" }, {\"contentType\": \"text\/html; charset=US-ASCII\",\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\",\"data\": \"<html><body>Problema al instalar Historian 6.0 Enterprise\r\n\r\nInfo Link: https:\/\/soporte.adasoft.es\/browse\/NOVTRACERT-24<\/body><\/html>\",\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"}]}"}
```

Comment: Show.Your.Code.  The backslashes you see in the string are virtual. They escape the double quotes to avoid breaking the string representation.

Comment: As @vadian says, show the code and also what you expect to see and what you are seeing.

Comment: Edit the post , any idea?

Comment: You haven't done what I asked. What has `dataToPost` got to do with `myBod`? And when I said "show what you are seeing" I didn't mean post another assignment statement", Show the output of the print statement .

Comment: dataPost is equal to myBod

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that this is the output you are seeing:

```
{
    "_Abstract": "Problema al instalar Historian 6.0 Enterprise  Info Link: https:\/\/soporte.adasoft.es\/browse\/NOVTRACERT-24",
    "Executor": "",
    "Watcher": [""],
    "Supervisor": "CÃ©sar Ramos",
    "Name": "NOVTRACERT-24",
    "Body": "{\"type\": \"multipart\",\"content\": [{\"contentType\": \"multipart\/alternative; Boundary=\\\"0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\\\"\",\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\" },{\"contentType\": \"text\/plain; charset=US-ASCII\",\"data\": \"Problema al instalar Historian 6.0 Enterprise\r\n\r\nInfo Link: https:\/\/soporte.adasoft.es\/browse\/NOVTRACERT-24\",\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\" }, {\"contentType\": \"text\/html; charset=US-ASCII\",\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\",\"data\": \"<html><body>Problema al instalar Historian 6.0 Enterprise\r\n\r\nInfo Link: https:\/\/soporte.adasoft.es\/browse\/NOVTRACERT-24<\/body><\/html>\",\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"}]}"
}
```

I ran it through [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to prettify it and check it is valid JSON. The `body` item is a string that happens (in this case) to contain JSON, but because it is serialised as a string inside another piece of JSON, all the JSON special characters need to be escaped (i.e. `"` and `\`). This is what you asked for and it is encoded correctly.

If you had wanted `body` to be a JSON object rather than a string, you would need to first convert it to JSON by deserialising it, then set the `body` key and then serialise the whole message.